# Tableau MySQL - "Convert to Custom SQL" generates invalid query

Tags: mysql, tableau-api

I am running Tableau with a connection to a MySQL Data Source. When I choose the "Convert to Custom SQL" option, I get an error. The error is as follows:

```
[MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver]Unknown column 'Name' in 'field list'
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT `TableauSQL`.`Name` AS `Name`
FROM (
  SELECT `projectData`.`_id` AS `_id`,
    `projectData`.`approvalfy` AS `approvalfy`,

... many columns, none of which are 'name' ...

    `projectData`.`url` AS `url`
  FROM `projectData`
) `TableauSQL`
LIMIT 10000
```

So why is Tableau generating a query where a non-existent column is selected?

Comment: You're receiving this error message in Tableau, or when you try to execute the query? I know you said none of the columns were "name", but could you please post the full query anyway.